# how to enable page one checkbox from page two using javascript or ajax or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

Here below code is in employee.php page

```
function enableComponents() {
    document.getElementById("PaySheet.php?'pEmployeeCB'").disabled = false;
}
```

here below code is in paysheet.php page

```
<input id="pEmployeeCB" type="checkbox" value="" />
```

My problem is I tried to trigger the enableComponent method in employee.php page. but in employee.php page, pEmployeeCB checkbox id of paysheet.php page didn't identify.

so how can i enable the checkbox of paysheet.php page at the employee.php page?

Comment: You can't disable checkbox on different page unless that page is open in different tab.

Comment: this two separated pages are load on same page using iframs, don't have a solution for my requirement?  cant use public keyword like in java ?

Comment: well you didn't mention they were iframed on the same parent page.. perhaps you should edit your question to explain that.  In any case, if everything is hosted on the same domain, you can use `parent.window.frames` to reference the context of iframeA within iframeB

Comment: if that other page is in iframe then you can use this using jQuery `$("#iFrame").contents().find("#pEmployeeCB").attr('disabled', false);`

Comment: $("#iFrame").contents().find("#pEmployeeCB").attr('disabled', false); this code is not working , i can see my two pages in same page, but i cant do effect to a page from one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "two pages" need to be on same domain to use iframe

To disable checkbox on parent page from iframe:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById("pEmployeeCB").disabled = false;
```

To disable checkbox on iframe page from parent page:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('your-iframe-id');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDocument.getElementById("pEmployeeCB").disabled = false;
```

Comment: thx , parent.document.getElementById("pEmployeeCB").disabled = false; this is working